# Is this system stable?

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system

I got this control system with such dynamics: 
\begin{equation}
\dot{x}(t)=-\frac{\partial{H(x)}}{\partial{x}},~H\geq 0,~H(x)=0\Rightarrow x=0
\end{equation}
$x(t)$ is a $n$-dimension vector, questions are: is this control system stable, if it is, how to find the balance point or points?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 0):

Pick a candidate Lyapunov function $H(x)$ and see how far you can get. The equilibria are the points where $\frac{\partial H}{\partial x} = 0$, but everything depends on the properties of $H$, which you have not specified.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, you answer has given me a hint. check with you later and thank you.